# If $f(f(n)) = 2n$ and $f(4n + 1) = 4n + 3$ -- where $n$ is any positive integer. What are the last three digits of $f(2016)$?

Tags: functions

Recently encountered the following question:

> A function $f$ defined on the set of positive integers has the properties that, for any positive integer $n$, $f(f(n)) = 2n$ and $f(4n + 1) = 4n + 3$ . What are the last three digits of $f(2016)$?

I tried to find the function, $f$. But was very unsuccessful. The closest I got was $f(x) = x+2$. However, it doesn't satisfy the composite; for instance, $f(f(10))$ is $14$ and not $2n$, i.e $20$. I then tried to apply the compound function on the other function given, i.e $f(f(4n+1)) = 2(4n+1)$. I don't know where I was going with that and ended up getting stuck again.

How would you solve this question (would you try to determine the function at all)? What would be the tools you use to attack this? If possible, can you please provide a solution to the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: So you know how to evaluate $f$ on odd integers $>4$. $$f(4n+1)=4n+3,\;f(4n+3)=8n+2$$How does that help you?

Comment: How did you get $f(4n+3) = 8n + 2$?

Comment: @AnhadArora $f(f(4n+1))=2(4n+1)$.

Comment: You should try applying f to both sides of f(f(n))=2n to see what f does to an even number 2n. Then you should factor 2016 into a power of two times a number of the form 4k+1 or 4k+3.

Comment: Thanks. From here would you try to determine $f$? Or would you do something else? If so, what?

Comment: $2016 = 63 * 2^5$ And $63$ is in the form $4n + 3$. What from here?

Comment: $2f(n)=f(f(f(n)))=f(2n)$ might be helpful

Comment: $f4(n) = 4n$ thus $fx(n) = xn$ where $fx(n) = f(x)$ compounded $x$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Prove that $f$ is injective. After that you can conclude that $f(2n)=2f(n)$ and then $$f(2n)=2f(n)\to f(2^k\cdot n)=2^kf(n)\quad (1)$$

Now you have to calculate $f(63)$. But, $63=4\cdot 15+3$.

Comment: Can you do $f64(63)$ ($f$ compounded $64$ times)? To get $f(2016)$? Would that help at all?

Comment: Alternatively could you find $n$ in $63 = 4n + 3$ as $n = 15$. Then determine that $f(4*15 + 1) = 63, f(61) = 63$?

Comment: @AnhadArora, if you find $f(63)$, which you should be able to do, yoiu only need to use equation $(1)$ to find $f(2016)$

Comment: I did the answer below, is that correct?

Comment: @AnhadArora, it is correct, but you can find it faster by using equation $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

From the factors of 2016, you can conclude that $2016 = 63 * 2^5$.

$63$ is the form $4n + 3$ from here we can conclude that $n = 15$

Since $f(4n + 1) = 4n + 3$ then $f(4 * 15 + 1) = 63, f(61) = 63$.

We can then apply the function again on $63$ or $f(61)$. Since $f(n) = 2n$ then $f(f(61)) = 2*61 = 122$.

We can then repeatedly apply the function $f$ to form a “chain”:

> $61 —> f(61) = 63 —> f(63) = f(f(61)) = 122 —> f(122) = f(f(63)) = 126 —> 61*4 —> 63*4 —> … —> 63*16 —> 61*32 —> 63*32 = 2016 —> f(2016) = 61*64 = 3904$.

From here we can see that $f(2016) = 3904$.

**Thus, the last 3 digits of $f(2016)$ is equal to $904$.**